# Linux Apache: can't access the second webapp from web browser

Tags: apache, web-applications

I have two files conf for two webapp (not two sites !). The first one runs on port 80 (redirect on 443) and it works perfectly. The second one runs on port 81 (redirect on port 444) but doesn't work: I can't access it from web browser.

I search on the net and I have checked the ports (all are open). Notice that I can access the second webapp directly on tomcat port. So I suppose the problem is apache configuration

I found on the net that we have to add in the conf files "NameVirtualHost *:81" etc...but nothing changes So i remove it.

When I start apache2, the log files are created in /var/log/apache2. When I acces the first web app from a web brower, his log file is updated. But when I access the second on, his log file doesn't change.

[image]

Here the first webapp config file (that works):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo-xxxxxxx.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://demo-xxxxxxx.fr:443/Demo
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxk.fr_ssl_certificate.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/_.xxxx.fr_private_key.key
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxx.fr_ssl_certificate.cer

ServerName demo-xxxxxx.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://demo-xxxxxxx.fr/Demo

#ServerAlias

Options -Indexes

# Encoded slashes need to be allowed
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# keep the host
ProxyPreserveHost On

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.demo_443.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.demo_443.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /share http://localhost:8080/share
ProxyPassReverse /share http://localhost:8080/share
ProxyPass /alfresco http://localhost:8080/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco http://localhost:8080/alfresco
...
```

Here is the second webapp config file that i can't access from web browser:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName myxxxxxx.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://myxxxxxx.fr:444/Myxxxxx
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:444>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxx.fr_ssl_certificate.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/_.xxxx.fr_private_key.key
SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxx.fr_ssl_certificate.cer

ServerName myxxxxx.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://myxxxxx.fr:444/Myxxxxx

#ServerAlias

Options -Indexes

# Encoded slashes need to be allowed
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

# keep the host
ProxyPreserveHost On

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.myxxx_444.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.myxxx_444.log combined

    ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /share http://localhost:18080/share
ProxyPassReverse /share http://localhost:18080/share
ProxyPass /alfresco http://localhost:18080/alfresco
ProxyPassReverse /alfresco http://localhost:18080/alfresco

....
```

I find example on the net but it's for 2 site on the same port. It's not my use case....

What is missing ?